# Getting last (newest) element with lxml,python

Tags: python, django, django-views, lxml

Hey everyone, I have had some amazing help the past couple days in trying to solve my issue.  I just have one last questions (I hope) :)

I am trying to get the last element from my xml and place it in a variable.  I am using django,python and the lxml library.

What I want to do is, go through the XML that I have got from the API call, find the newest project, (it will have the largest ID number) then assign it to a variable to store in my database.   I am having some trouble finding out how to find that latest, newest, element.

Here is a code snippet:

```
req2 = urllib2.Request("http://web_url/public/api.php?path_info=/projects&token=#########")
        resp = urllib2.urlopen(req2)
        resp_data = resp.read()
        if not resp.code == '200' and resp.headers.get('content-type') == 'text/xml':
          # Do your error handling.
          raise Exception('Unexpected response',req2,resp)
        data = etree.XML(resp_data)
        #assigns the api_id to the id at index of 0 for time being,  using the // in front of project makes sure that its looking at the correct node inside of the projects structure
        api_id = int(data.xpath('//project/id/text()')[0])
        project.API_id = api_id
        project.save()
```

As of right now, it takes the element at [0] and stores the ID just fine, but I need the latest/newest/etc element instead.

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Are the elements ordered, i.e. will the one with the largest ID be the last in the XML? (If so, ubuntu has the right answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change `[0]` to `[-1]` to select the **last** element in the list:

```
api_id = int(data.xpath('//project/id/text()')[-1])
```

Note that this may not give you the **largest** `id` value if the largest is not at the end of the list.

To get the largest `id`, you could do this:

```
api_id = max(map(int,data.xpath('//project/id/text()')))
```

Comment: perfect, I am not sure why I didn't think of that sooner!